# Completion of an algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Based on [arXiv:math/9802041v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802041#), there is a definition for $NC$-filtration and $NC$-completion of an associated algebra over the complex numbers:

Let $R$ be an associative algebra and $R^{\rm Lie} = (R, [a,b] = ab -
ba)$ be $R$ regarded as a ${\rm Lie}$ algebra.
By definition the following hold:

(a) The NC-filtration of $R$ is the
decreasing filtration $\{F^dR\}_{d\ge 0}$ where $F^dR$ is the two-sided
ideal
$$F^dR = \sum_m \sum_{i_1+\cdots+ i_m -m = d} R \cdot R^{\rm Lie}_{i_1}
\cdot R \cdot{\kern 1.5pt}{\cdots}{\kern 1.5pt}\cdot R\cdot R^{\rm
Lie}_{i_m}\cdot R.$$

(b) For an associative algebra $R$ its NC-completion is the algebra
$$R_{[ ab ]} = \lim_{\leftarrow} R/F^dR.$$
My question is: How can we generalize this definition to a Noetherian $R$-algebra $A$, when $R$ is a commutative Noetherian ring?

Comment: I suggest to not call $A$'s base ring $R$ but $k$ or something similar, because $(A,k)$ plays the role of $(R,\mathbb{C})$ at the beginning. Besides from the confusing notation, can't you apply the definition of $F^dR$ and $R_{[ab]}$ literarly to $A$ ?

Comment: First, I think your suggestion about the base ring to be an algebraically closed field is interesting. Second, for your question, it's not necessary.

Comment: (1) I didn't suggest an algebraically closed field as base ring, I just suggest to rename the latter $R$ by $k$ or something similar to not mix it with the former $R$. (2) Could you please elaborate why you think the definitions you wrote down for $F^dR$ and $R_{[ab]}$ don't apply to $A$ in general ?